# Convert word doc text to HTML div through contenteditable DIV

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert the word doc text to HTML like below

1. Making a DIV with `contenteditable = true`
2. Pasting the word text to the editable DIV, as it allows pasting formatting also.
3. Next I am getting the innerHTML of DIV

But with this approach I am not getting the proper HTML. Apart from hell lot of dirty MS Word formatting, sometimes it is replacing `space` value of text with `new line`.

Is there any better way to do the above thing and why it is replacing it with `new line`.

Answer (score 0):

I use [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) for this. They have a "paste from Word" option that allows you to strip out all of the MS stuff. The same option exists in [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), which some of the sites I work on use  it or fck (old version).

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am sorry to say that it does not help me. Cause they are providing the editing option to generate HTML, so everything will be in editor control. But I am looking for some kind of solution which can convert the existing word doc text to HTML

Comment: There are extensive editor configurations to limit what they can and can't do. Someone could just as simply insert code into the Word document and submit it that way. You would need to run `strip_tags()` on the inbound code before allowing it to be printed anyhow. `<script>` can contain bad things.